# Accumulating message outputs in a specified order

Tags: elixir

I want to accumulate the output of messages sent by different processes in a specified order.

For example, I have a list of pids `[pid0, pid1]`. If I get `pid0` first, then fine. If I get `pid1` first, then nothing will happen until I get `pid0`.

I know that this can be resolved by using maps or keyword lookups and ordering after all the messages have been received. However, is this possible to do by pattern matching?

For example, writing something like this to guarantee it's only trying to receive a message `input_pid` (the first message in the list):

```
defp loop([input_pid | remaining_input_pids], acc) do
  receive do
    {:forward, ^input_pid, output} -> loop(remaining_input_pids, [output | acc])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first see a non-working example and then find a way to fix it:

```
caller = self

pids = for x <- 1..100 do
  spawn fn ->
    :random.seed(:erlang.monotonic_time)
    :timer.sleep(:random.uniform(1000))
    send(caller, x)
  end
end

for _ <- pids do
  receive do
    x -> IO.inspect(x)
  end
end
```

This spawns 100 processes, where each one sleeps for a random amount of time before sending `x` back to the caller. Later, the results are received in the order they are sent back, which will be random.

If we want to get the results in the order the processes were spawned, we need to give the receiving process a hint. As you correctly observed, we can use the spawned process' `pid` to do that. We obtain the `pid` in the caller as the return value from `spawn`, but we can also get the `pid` of a spawned process by calling `self` inside the process and then send it back to the caller:

```
caller = self

pids = for x <- 1..100 do
  spawn fn ->
    :random.seed(:erlang.monotonic_time)
    :timer.sleep(:random.uniform(1000))
    send(caller, {self, x})
  end
end

for pid <- pids do
  receive do
    {^pid, x} -> IO.inspect(x)
  end
end
```

Just be aware that this might flood the caller's process inbox. In the worst case,  the process spawned first might be received last and then all the other messages will stick around until the end.

Now, whether you need to go one step further depends on the number of processes and you should benchmark the results for you specific case. The problem with a large number of processes is how the mailbox is processed: every time you call `receive`, it will loop through *all* messages until a match is found. That means in the worst case you are iterating over the mailbox `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n*(n+1)/2` times (quadratic time complexity `O(n²)`), which can become a bottleneck.

In such a case, a better option might be to receive the messages immediately, store them in a map and then read them out in the correct order. The downside of this is that you *always* have to wait until all messages are received. With the first approach, the messages are processed as soon as the next one in order arrives. Here's an example of how to do that. In this case I used 100,000 processes, which already gets very slow with the other approach:

```
caller = self

pids = for x <- 1..100_000 do
  spawn fn ->
    :random.seed(:erlang.monotonic_time)
    :timer.sleep(:random.uniform(1000))
    send(caller, {self, x})
  end
end

results = Enum.reduce pids, %{}, fn(_, results) ->
  receive do
    {pid, x} -> Map.put(results, pid, x)
  end
end

for pid <- pids do
  IO.inspect(results[pid])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I've went with a different version that uses straight patten matching. But because it was so interesting, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

@patrick-oscity has given a really in-depth answer and I like it a lot. However, I've gone with a version that can do this just using pattern matching against the pin operator.

For context, I'm writing an accumulator that forwards the results of all its inputs to an actuator when all the inputs have been received. I also want the accumulated output, which is a list, to respect a pre-defined order of the processes that originally sent their outputs.

After it does this, the accumulator then starts to wait for messages again.

The accumulator looks like this:

```
def start_link(actuator, actuator_pid) do
  Task.start_link(fn -> loop(actuator, actuator_pid, actuator.inputs, []) end)
end

defp loop(actuator, actuator_pid, [], acc) do
  result = acc |> Enum.reverse
  send actuator_pid, {:forward, self(), result}
  loop(actuator, actuator_pid, actuator.inputs, [])
end

defp loop(actuator, actuator_pid, [input | remaining_inputs], acc) do
  receive do
    {:forward, ^input, output} ->
      loop(actuator, actuator_pid, remaining_inputs, [output | acc])
  end
end
```

To prove it does what I want, the tests for this are as follows:

```
test "When I recieve the outputs from all my inputs, then I return the accumulated result in the order of my actuator's inputs" do

{_, pid0} = Task.start_link(fn -> test_loop end)
{_, pid1} = Task.start_link(fn -> test_loop end)
{_, pid2} = Task.start_link(fn -> test_loop end)

actuator = %Cerebrum.Actuator{
  inputs: [pid0, pid1, pid2]
}

actuator_pid = self()
{_, pid} = start_link(actuator, actuator_pid)

send pid, {:forward, pid0, 0}
refute_receive {:forward, pid, [0]}

send pid, {:forward, pid1, 1}
refute_receive {:forward, pid, [0, 1]}

send pid, {:forward, pid2, 2}
assert_receive {:forward, pid, [0, 1, 2]}

send pid, {:forward, pid0, 0}
send pid, {:forward, pid1, 1}
send pid, {:forward, pid2, 2}
assert_receive {:forward, pid, [0, 1, 2]}

send pid, {:forward, pid0, 0}
send pid, {:forward, pid2, 2}
send pid, {:forward, pid1, 1}
assert_receive {:forward, pid, [0, 1, 2]}

send pid, {:forward, pid1, 1}
send pid, {:forward, pid0, 0}
send pid, {:forward, pid2, 2}
assert_receive {:forward, pid, [0, 1, 2]}

send pid, {:forward, pid1, 1}
send pid, {:forward, pid2, 2}
send pid, {:forward, pid0, 0}
assert_receive {:forward, pid, [0, 1, 2]}

send pid, {:forward, pid2, 2}
send pid, {:forward, pid1, 1}
send pid, {:forward, pid0, 0}
assert_receive {:forward, pid, [0, 1, 2]}

send pid, {:forward, pid2, 2}
send pid, {:forward, pid1, 1}
send pid, {:forward, pid0, 0}
assert_receive {:forward, pid, [0, 1, 2]}

end

defp test_loop do
  test_loop
end
```

Comment: I think that this basically boils down to my first approach, seems good from my perspective!